# Why is this vb array initialized with -1?

Tags: vb.net

I found the following line of code:

```vb
Public BUSHEL_TYPES As NameValuePair()
BUSHEL_TYPES = New NameValuePair(-1) {}
```

What does it mean to initialize an array with a negative one in the parenthesis?
It seems to have the same effect as:

```vb
BUSHEL_TYPES = New NameValuePair() {}
```

But I want to be sure before I take the -1 out. If it's not necessary the negative one will confuse everyone like it has me. Using a number >= 0 causes the array to have elements; using -2 causes an error

> error BC30611: Array dimensions cannot have a negative size.

Comment: `NameValuePair` is not an array. It's an object that takes a signed integer constructor.

Comment: `...As NameValuePair()` makes it a Type.  There are 3 of them I can find in the Net FrameWork, but it is not an uncommon name for a simple...well, name-value pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-1` means `null` or `empty`

> **Dimension Length**
>
> The index of each dimension is 0-based, which means
>   it ranges from 0 through its upper bound. Therefore, the length of a
>   given dimension is greater by 1 than the declared upper bound for that
>   dimension.
>   [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b388cb5s.aspx)

Above means that if you would put 0 there the `length` would be `1`. If you put `-1` or nothing the `length` will be `0`.

```
BUSHEL_TYPES = New NameValuePair(-1) {}
```

Above code initialize array of `lenght 0`

```
BUSHEL_TYPES = New NameValuePair(0) {}
```

Above code initialize array of `lenght 1`

```
BUSHEL_TYPES = New NameValuePair() {}
```

Above code initialize array of `lenght 0`

**You do not need `-1` in there**

Comment: This question is about VB.Net - your quote is about C#.

Comment: Didn't realize. I will fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Also note that C# is different in that an array declaration specifies the *length* rather than the *upper bound*.  Thus using a -1 in C# would result in the same error noted in the question.

Comment: Actually, if you do `New NameValuePair (Nothing){}` you get an array with one element, so `-1` strickly speaking is not equivalent to `Nothing`. It does seem to be the equivalent to the dimension length not being specified, but did you find any documentation that mentions `-1`?

Comment: I did not, but I remember few years back I was "modernizing" some code older code and it had -1 everywhere. That confused me for a while. My guess is that this approach was originally taught way back.